# Decode 21x21 QR-Code in Python

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, qr-code

I am trying to decode version 1 QR codes with a size of 21x21 pixels. Currently, I am using the `zbarlight` module, but unfortunately I am not able to decode [QR codes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xGAu6.jpg) (click the link for a sample) with it.

Here is my code:

```
import zbarlight

with open(file_name, 'rb') as image_file:
    image = Image.open(image_file)  
    image.load()
    codes = zbarlight.scan_codes('qrcode', image)
    print('QR codes: %s' % codes)
```

I tried several QR codes but I always get this output:

> QR codes: None